# Convert image URLs to Drawables

Tags: java, android

I need to turn image URLs to `Drawable`s so I can use it in an `int` array.

I want to put `d0`, `d1`, `d3`, etc. instead of the `R.drawable.sample_0`, `R.drawable.sample_1`, etc.

What I don't understand is why `R.drawable.photos` are being detected as `int` while my `Drawable`s are not?

How can turn my `Drawable`s to `int`?

```
public void callEditActivity(){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, BirdsGalleryActivity.class);
    img0 = myIntent.getExtras().getString("IMG0");
    img1 = myIntent.getExtras().getString("IMG1");
    img2 = myIntent.getExtras().getString("IMG2");
    img3 = myIntent.getExtras().getString("IMG3");
    img4 = myIntent.getExtras().getString("IMG4");
}

URL url0 = new URL(img0);
URL url1 = new URL(img1);
URL url2 = new URL(img2);
URL url3 = new URL(img3);
URL url4 = new URL(img4);

Bitmap bmp0 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url0.openConnection().getInputStream());
Bitmap bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url1.openConnection().getInputStream());
Bitmap bmp2 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url2.openConnection().getInputStream());
Bitmap bmp3 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url3.openConnection().getInputStream());
Bitmap bmp4 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url4.openConnection().getInputStream());

Drawable d0 = new BitmapDrawable(bmp0);
Drawable d1 = new BitmapDrawable(bmp1);
Drawable d2 = new BitmapDrawable(bmp2);
Drawable d3 = new BitmapDrawable(bmp3);
Drawable d4 = new BitmapDrawable(bmp4);

private int[] GalImages = new int[] {
        R.drawable.sample_0,
        R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2,
};
```

Comment: Your drawables are of type Drawable not int. The ints are only for drawables from resource. Which at design time are put in the drawable folder.

Comment: So how I can treat my drawables as drawables from resources (without downloading them at design time to the drawable folder)?

Comment: Well you cant was the message.

Comment: Well if I use the picasso method and get its resource ref from the loaded imageview, will that work?

Comment: What do you consider to be the picasso method?